# What is the fundamental difference between linkedin.com and skillpages.com?

Tags: linkedin

I have found no fundamental difference between `linkedin.com` and `skillpages.com`.

Why is `skillpages.com`'s popularity growing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SkillPages seems to rely more on skills than professional network reach which LinkedIn started with.

The formality seems to be lower in SkillPages as well.

As the about page and video suggests, it's a site that is used to find people with a specific skill set which may not be possible in professional networking sites like LinkedIn that rely on more resume style information.

Example: I cannot find a drummer who also sings on LinkedIn